# How to know if an Laravel API Resource is being loaded from another API resource?

Tags: laravel, laravel-api, laravel-resource

I have 2 API Resource classes related to each other. The structure of these classes is as follows:

`EmployeeResource`

```
class EmployeeResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'gender' => GenderResource::make($this->gender),
        ];
    }
}
```

`GenderResource`

```
class GenderResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'employees' => EmployeeResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('employees')),
        ];
    }
}
```

I need class `EmployeeResource` to always return all the attributes of the employee, including their `gender`. I have a model where I store the different genders that can be associated with an employee. In this case, an employee must contain a gender and a gender can be associated with several employees (a one-to-many relationship). The relationships are created in the respective models (`Employee` and `Gender`).

I need when the `EmployeeResource` resource is returned, it always returns the `gender` that the employee has. But when the `GenderResource` resource is returned with the `employee` relation loaded, it returns the `EmployeeResource` resource, but without the `gender` property, since it would be redundant. For example:

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $resource = Employee::all();

        return EmployeeResource::collection(Employee::all());
    }
}
```

Should return something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Employee 1",
            "gender": {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Female"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I do:

```
class GenderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $resource = Gender::with('employees')->all();

        return GenderResource::collection($resource);
    }
}
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Female",
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Employee 1"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the `employees` attribute does not contain the `gender` attribute. I can't find any way to know in the `EmployeeResource` resource if it is being loaded from another resource, in this case, `GenderResource`, because if so, I could apply the `when()`, `unless()`, etc. methods.

Comment: I would create `EmployeeResource` and `EmployeeWithoutRelationResource`, so second-one will return only id and name, and first-one, EmployeeResource, will extends EmployeeWithoutRelationResource and return smth like `return array_merge(parent::toArray($request), ['gender' => GenderResource::make($this->gender)])`, so GenderResource can use `EmployeeWithoutRelationResource`